# Computing a divergent integral $\iiint r^5sin\theta cos\theta$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

***Problem***

Evaluate

$$I =  \iiint_V z \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz$$

Where V is :
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$

***Solution:***

I must use spherical coordinates so:
$$x=r\cos\psi \sin{\theta}$$
$$y=r \sin{\psi} \sin{\theta}$$
$$z = r \cos \theta$$ 
$$r \geq 0;  0 \leq \psi \leq 2 \pi; 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$$

Jacobian matrix ***J***= $r^2sin\theta$

The new ***V*** looks like this:
$$\sqrt{r^2\cos^2 \psi \sin^{2} \theta + r^2 \sin^{2} \psi \sin^{2} \theta} \leq r\cos \theta \leq \sqrt{1-(r^2\cos^2 \psi \sin^2 \theta + r^{2}\sin^2\psi \sin^{2}\theta)}$$

From these we conclude that:
$$\sin \theta \leq \cos \theta$$
$$r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin \theta}; r \leq 1$$

And so the new V is:
$$ 0 \leq r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin \theta}$$
$$ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$$
$$0 \leq \psi \leq 2\pi$$

And so our integral is:

$$\int \limits_0^{2\pi }\int \limits_0^{\frac{\pi \:}{4}}\int \limits^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\theta \right)}}_0r^4\cos\left(\theta \right)\sin \left(\theta \right)drd\theta \:d\psi $$

**Question** here somewhere I a may be making a mistake, because later on the integral is diverging

\begin{align}
\int \limits_0^{2\pi }\int \limits_0^{\frac{\pi \:}{4}}\int \limits^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\theta \right)}}_0r^4\cos\left(\theta \right)\sin \left(\theta \right)drd\theta \:d\psi &= \frac{1}{5} \int \int r^{5}\cos\theta \sin{\theta} \in[0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\theta]\\
&=\frac{1}{20\sqrt{2}} \int \int \frac{d \sin\theta}{\sin^{4}\theta}\\
&= \frac{-3}{20\sqrt{2}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin^{2}\theta} |^{\pi/4}_{0} d\psi
\end{align}
 and here in $\sin(0)$ the integral is diverging

***Question:***
What can I do about this problem? Am I making a mistake? What Should I fix? What is the solution to this Integral?

***Update***

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$

to spherical coordinates

$$\sqrt{r^2\cos^2 \psi \sin^{2} \theta + r^2 \sin^{2} \psi \sin^{2} \theta} \leq r\cos \theta \leq \sqrt{1-(r^2\cos^2 \psi \sin^2 \theta + r^{2}\sin^2\psi \sin^{2}\theta)}$$

$$r \sin{\theta} \leq r \cos{\theta} \leq \sqrt{1-r^{2} \sin^{2}{\theta}}$$

And From here:
$$\sin{\theta} \leq  \cos{\theta}$$
$$r \leq 1 $$
$$r^{2} \sin^{2}{\theta} \leq 1 - r^{2} \sin^{2}{\theta} <=> r^{2} \sin^{2}{\theta} +r^{2} \sin^{2}{\theta} \leq 1 <=> r^{2} \leq \frac{1}{2 sin^{2} \theta} <=> r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} sin{\theta}} $$

Comment: How do you conclude $r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin \theta}$ ?

Comment: When you satisfy both inequalities ( LHS $\leq$ Middle and Middle $\leq$ RHS) you automatically satisfy LHS $\leq$ RHS. Since already $\sin \theta \leq \cos \theta$ you get $r \leq 1 \leq 1/\sqrt{2} \sin\theta$, in other words you are using the wrong upper integration boundary  for $r$. There is also a mistake in the last step, but the result would still diverge.

Comment: @RonaldBlaak how is 1≤1/sqrt{2}sinθ ? For which \theta is this statement true ?

Comment: @Andreas Check my update

Comment: Since $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ it follows from $\sin \theta \leq \cos \theta$ that $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$ and hence $0 \leq \sin \theta \leq 1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So it is sufficient to integrate $r$ up to $r=1$ as the upper limit and with that you would get convergent integrals and the correct finite volume.

Comment: Again, $r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin \theta}$ is obsolete since  $r \leq 1 \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin \theta}$ and you require  $r \leq 1$ anyway, so this is the stronger condition. Why is  $ 1 \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin \theta}$ ? Well, you are regarding $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$ , so this is equivalent to $ \sin \theta \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $, so this holds since $ \sin \pi/4 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $.

Comment: @Andreas ok, now I understand, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not the slightest reason why the integral of a nice function over a compact domain should be divergent.

I'm using geographical longitude $\phi$ and geographical latitude $-{\pi\over 2}\leq\theta\leq{\pi\over2}$. The condition $z\geq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then translates into $r\sin\theta\geq r\cos\theta$, or $\theta\geq{\pi\over4}$, and the condition $z\leq\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ translates into $r\leq 1$. Since the Jacobian is $r^2\cos\theta$ we obtain
$$I=2\pi\int_0^1\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} r\sin\theta\ r\ r^2\cos\theta\>d\theta\>dr=2\pi\int_0^1r^4\>dr\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\cos\theta\>d\theta={\pi\over10}\ .$$

Comment: I know the integral shouldn't diverge, I've made a mistake in computing it. I believe I've made an error when setting the coordinates. I've made an Update, Check it out.